# Vintage short story of school kids studying a lethal alien design

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, authors

I am trying to remember the title and author of a classic sci-fi short story / novella involving an alien invasion.  It is difficult to fight the aliens because they use images designed to disrupt brain function and kill humans who look at them.  In the story, one of the kids parents belongs to the government agency to study and counter these lethal designs.  The kids get a hold of one of the designs, and repeatedly expose themselves to it in ever increasing lengths of time, building immunity.  Anyone remember this?  If I had a bet, I'd say I probably read it in The Road To Science Fiction or The Science Fiction Hall Of Fame series.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any idea when it was you read this story?

Comment: [Different Kinds of Darkness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14725/what-was-this-short-story-terrorists-use-images-to-kill-people-set-in-a-schoo)? Though that's terrorists not aliens

Comment: Well.. I read it in the 90s/2000s, but I have a bad habit of picking up very old science fiction novels and anthologies.  IIRC, the story reads like very 50's or early 60's.  Kinda before character driven sci fi was a thing.

Comment: YES!! This is it!!  Thank you so much @John Rennie!! :)

Answer (score 0):

@John Rennie had it right!  It is Different Kinds Of Darkness by Dave Langford.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to provide a bit more info on the book, such as the date of publication and an outline of the plot, or at least the specific plot details that you described in the question. Feel free to quote text from sites such as Goodreads or Amazon, and please provide links to any pages you do quote text from.

Comment: It'd also be appreciated if you'd mark this answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, although the site won't allow a self-answer like this to be marked as accepted until 48 hours have elapsed since the question was initially asked.